# Powershell Loop through Format-Table

Tags: powershell, foreach, formattable

I've got a question.
I've created a format-table with filename, source- and destination directory.
Now I try to loop through the table with a foreach.
Inside this loop i want to move the files from the source- to destination directory. My problem is to get the items from the row.

Here is my example code:

```
cls
$MovePathSource = "C:\Users\user\Desktop\sourcefolder"
$MovePathDestination = "C:\Users\user\Desktop\destinationfolder"

$filetypes = @("*.llla" , "html")
$table = dir $MovePathSource -Recurse -Include $filetypes | Format-Table@{Expression={$_.Name};Label="Filename"},@{Expression={($_.DirectoryName)};Label="Sourcepath"},@{Expression={($_.DirectoryName).Replace($MovePathSource,$MovePathDestination)};Label="Destinationpath"}

$table

foreach ($row in $table)
{
write-host "$row.Sourcepath"
#Move-Item -Path ($row.Sourcepath + "\" + $row.Filename) -Destination $row.Destinationpath
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Never use `Format-*`-cmdlets before your done with the data. Even then, only use it when displaying something to a user (or creating a mail etc.) as they break the original data and only leave you with special format-objects.

Replace `Format-Table` With `Select-Object` to get the same result while keeping usable objects.

```
$table = dir $MovePathSource -Recurse -Include $filetypes |
Select-Object @{Expression={$_.Name};Label="Filename"},@{Expression={($_.DirectoryName)};Label="Sourcepath"},@{Expression={($_.DirectoryName).Replace($MovePathSource,$MovePathDestination)};Label="Destinationpath"}
```

Answer (score 2):

The `format-table` cmdlet is to **format the output** of a command as a table. If you want to work with the objects, use a `select` instead:

```
$table = dir $MovePathSource -Recurse -Include $filetypes | select @{Expression={$_.Name};Label="Filename"},@{Expression={($_.DirectoryName)};Label="Sourcepath"},@{Expression={($_.DirectoryName).Replace($MovePathSource,$MovePathDestination)};Label="Destinationpath"}
```

Now you can access the properties like you tried in your comment. If you want to print the table, then you can use `$table | format-table`